# Question about inheritance and properties

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

I have a "base" class which contains following properties:

```
    public virtual Vector3b SIZE { get { return new Vector3b(16, 16, 16); } }

    public virtual Vector3b MAX
    {
        get { return new Vector3b(
                    (byte)(this.SIZE.X - 1), 
                    (byte)(this.SIZE.Y - 1), 
                    (byte)(this.SIZE.Z - 1)); 
            }
    }
```

Now, if I override SIZE property in my class which inherits from the base class, does MAX then calculate SIZE from base class or from inherited class ( or should it be just SIZE without this ) ?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, Vector3b is just basicly Vector3 but it uses bytes instead of floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MAX` will use the derived class `SIZE` if the runtime type of `this` reference is the derived type. It's called *dynamic dispatch* of virtual methods and properties, based on the *runtime* type of the object.

```
class X
{

   public virtual Vector3b SIZE { get { return new Vector3b(16, 16, 16); } }

    public virtual Vector3b MAX
    {
        get { return new Vector3b(
                    (byte)(this.SIZE.X - 1), 
                    (byte)(this.SIZE.Y - 1), 
                    (byte)(this.SIZE.Z - 1)); 
            }
    }
}

class Y : X
{
    public virtual Vector3b SIZE { get { return new Vector3b(26, 26, 26); } }
}

 X x = new X();
 var xmax = x.MAX ;// MAX uses X's SIZE

 Y y = new Y();
 var ymax = y.MAX ;// MAX uses Y's SIZE
```

Answer (score 6):

A virtual property or method by definition dispatches the method based on the *runtime* type of the receiver. In your example, if the runtime type is the derived class, then the derived property is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you override the virtual property the inherited class will use everything from the inherited class.

Answer (score -1):

Your derived class would use the overridden SIZE.